# automapper post "ForMember" properties

Tags: c#, automapper, ef-core-2.2

i'm new with automapper and i have a problem with navigation properties mapping.
I have create a map like this :

```
CreateMap<ObjEntity, ObjEntityViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LabelName,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.IdNavigation.LabelName)).ReverseMap();
```

it made a flat object and it works fine. But when i post back ObjEntityViewModel from my Edit Form, the property "LabelName" is always null. It appears all properties define with ForMember always null when it post back from my html form.
I don't understand why is it null and how can i resolve this problem.

My controller code :

```
public MesObsIndividusController(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;            
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundViewResult("NotFound");
            }

            var mesObsIndividus = await _observationService.GetMesObsindividus(id.Value);
            if (mesObsIndividus == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundViewResult("NotFound");
            }

            //mapping du ViewModel
            var mesVM = _mapper.Map<ObjEntityViewModel>(mesObsIndividus);

            return (mesVM);
}

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, ObjEntityViewModel mesObsIndividus)            
        {
            if (id != mesObsIndividus.IdMes)
            {
                return new NotFoundViewResult("NotFound");
            }



            if (ModelState.IsValid){
                //do update database stuff

            }else
            {
                return View(mesObsIndividus);
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Details), new { id = mesObsIndividus.IdMes });
        }
```

My html code :

```
@model Proj.Models.ObjEntityViewModel
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdMes"  />

    <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LibEspece" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LibEspece" id="LbEspece" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LibEspece" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LabelName)
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LabelName)
                </dd>
    </dl>

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank's

I use EF core 2.2 and automapper 6.0.0

Comment: Attach your Html to the question...

Comment: Is it possible the src entity isn't fully hydrated due to lazy loading of navigation properties?  can you confirm that the object you're mapping from actually has a non-null `IdNavigation` property with a non-null `LabelName` property?

Comment: @GPW When i load my edit form with my "automapping" ViewModel i get the correct value of all my properties. But when i post the form, the ViewModel get null value for LabelName. I don't think automapper do another treatment when i just post the Viewmodel ? The viewModel is staitic or still dynamic ?

Comment: Don't you have to have some kind of input to persist the value of label name? And I guess it is a bad practice to mix @Html helpers with tag helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't persist the LabelName in your form.

Using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LabelName)` or `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LabelName)` is not generating input tags from which the value of LabelName can be 'collected' by submission of the form.

You have to have something like this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="LabelName"  />
```

Comment: Thank's @Mikołaj Mularczyk, you save my time and solve my problem.